# Meaning of 'saving' in 'not one single saving vice'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [He is] devoid of any human weakness, with not one single
>   **saving** vice, sans prejudice, procrastination, ill-nature,
>   avarice, and absence of mind, as careful for his own safety
>   as he is for that of others, this excellent but odious character
>   stands like a monument in our courts of justice, vainly
>   appealing to his fellow citizens to order their lives after his
>   own example.
>
> A. P. Herbert, Uncommon Law (Methuen, 1969), p. 4

Would someone please explain what **saving** here means? Which [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/saving?q=saving) fits?

Source: P48, Law, Raymond Wacks

Comment: "saving" here could be substituted with "redeeming", if that is a more familiar use.  Either way, this language is intentionally tricky for humorous purposes.

Comment: This sense of *saving* seldom goes with a negative attribute such as *vice* -- the usual expression is *saving grace* (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+saving+grace). Here, it's a kind of deliberate pun on the idiom.

Comment: On Language Log: *The essay takes a few digs at the notion of "reasonableness" and at everyday hypocrisy* http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/2006_04.html (scroll down to/ search: 'saving vice')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must understand this as ironic. The usual phrase is 'saving grace' - the positive quality that compensates for the negatives. Don't think about *saving* as a noun. This is 'saving as adjective'. Here's the OED:

> **saving**, adj.
>
> Pronunciation:  Brit.  /ˈseɪvɪŋ/ , U.S. /ˈseɪvɪŋ/
>
> Forms:  see *save* v.   and -*ing* suffix2
>
> Etymology:
> < save v. + -ing suffix2.
>
> 1. a. *Theol*. That preserves a person or soul from damnation; that offers redemption from sin.
>
> b. That delivers, rescues, or preserves
> from danger; that protects or guards from anything undesirable.
>
> c.
> That delivers a person from moral or intellectual error; (of a
> quality) serving to mitigate (unqualified) condemnation or censure;
> redeeming. See also *saving grace* n. 2.
>
> d. As the second element in
> compounds: that redeems, rescues, protects, or preserves what is
> specified by the first element. *health*-, *life*-, *soul*-, *world-saving*,
> etc.: see the first element.

The person described is the opposite of this: this person is excellent without any 'saving vice'.

Comment: Then why 'vice?'

Comment: If you take the position that someone who is too perfect is unattractive, then the vice 'saves' or 'redeems' this person from this too-perfect image.